# How to calculate winning percentage in a poker game?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory

In some of the online poker apps they show winning percentage - which I interpret as chances of winning. How to calculate that - I understand that it is based on combinatorics. Suppose at Flop I have to find the winning percentage. At Flop 2 community cards are yet to appear. Suppose there are 6 players. None of them has folded. Each player has been dealt 2 hole cards. So I know what these 12 cards are. I know 3 community cards. Totally 15 cards are known to me. Rest of the 2 community cards could be chosen from 52 - 15 = 37 cards.

Comment: For such a big amount of players in such a complicated situation, it's impossible to do by hand on the spot. But yeah it all boils down to combinatorics. I'd take a look at the concept of "outs"

Comment: @David, thanks for taking interest. At Flop stage to choose 2 out of 37 cards leading to 37 * 36/2 combinations = 666.In each of the cases we can find out the winner. Say the players are A, B, C, D, E, F. Suppose in 100 cases A wins, B wins in 130 cases etc. So for A winning %age is 100/666 etc. This is my line of thinking.